# What is the proper way adding background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add `background image` in a section with full width. But I can't figure out what is the proper way to add image in CSS using `background-image`.

So, here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="main-banner">
 <div class="banner">               
  <h1>This H1 title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at tempor turpis. Suspendisse mattis, est eget volutpat elementum, lacus odio euismod ipsum, a placerat ligula mi ut nibh. In vitae leo facilisis, accumsan massa ultrices,</p>
 </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-banner { 
  background: url('../img/banner-img.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My image was not showing properly.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem, is the image displaying at all? If it is, is part of it being cut off or something? It would be great if you could host the image somewhere and give us a [mcve] so we can see the actual problem.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I just updated my question. See what i mean there, hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#main-banner { 
background: url('../img/banner-img.png') no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: if you need to full height , then you need to call the image inline , otherwise you need to set min height

Comment: That's working, but can that be full height if I really want to use CSS background-image to call my image?

Comment: try to use `background-size:100% 100%;`